# How to assign labels to tuples in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, tuples, perceptron

I'm new to Python and I'm having trouble with simple stuff. I'm trying to implement perceptron for random `(x,y)`s. I have two classes `N` and `P` and I want data from class `N` to have `1` as label and data from class `P` to have `0` as label for further calculations. `N` and `P` are defined like this:

```
random_positive = np.random.normal(100,45,100)
random_negative = np.random.normal(-100,45,100)
N=[(x,y) for x,y in zip(random_positive,random_negative)] 
P=[(x,y) for x,y in zip(random_negative,random_positive)]
```

I wrote the following code but the results are not what I expect.

```
for (x,y) in N:
    z = 1
for (x,y) in P:
    z = 0
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish here. `z` is a variable, that you simply keep overwriting in a loop. I'm not sure what you are expecting it to be. As an aside, `[(x,y) for x,y in zip(random_positive,random_negative)]` is a overly verbose way of doing `list(zip(random_positive, random_negative))`

Comment: Anyway, your error is occuring because you are trying to *call* `z`, which will simply be `0` after your two loops, since you are just overwriting the same variable. Indeed, both your loops could be replaced by simply `z = 0` to have the same result. Anyway, `int` objects aren't callable, hence the error.

Comment: `z` is an int. Why do you  `z()` ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm trying to implement perceptron for random (x,y)s. I have two classes N and P and I want data from class N to have 1 as label and data from class P to have 0 as label for further calculations.

Comment: Yes, but why are you calling `z(-86.33603121 , 82.69993369)` when you just assigned an int to `z`?  That's why you've got a type error.  It has nothing to do with tuples or anything.

Comment: Ok, then you need to use some sort of data structure to represent that. Just assigning to a variable will not accomplish what you are trying to accomplish, this really has nothing to do with `tuple` objects. You probably want to use a nested `list`, or probably a `numpy.ndarray` (I'll note, you've tagged this with numpy).

Comment: seems like you want a list of dicts.

Comment: @mdk why? The OP probably shouldn't be using `tuple` objects at all, but sticking to `numpy.ndarray` objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm using tuples because I'm also plotting the data using matplotlib and this is the only way I know.

Comment: @FreeSoul what? `matplotlib` works natively with `numpy.ndarray` objects, which again, is probably what you want. So instead of zip, do `np.stack([random_positive, random_negative], axis=0)`, or juse keep the columns seperate, depending on the plot you want to use.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Named tuples are are a possible way answer to the question "How to assign labels to tuples in Python?"

Comment: @mdk no, not really an answer to that at all, because the OP is talking about labels in the context of a data set, i.e. a third column with the "labels" (0 or 1) corresponding to that row of data.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are right, seems I misunderstood the intention of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
random_positive = np.random.normal(100,45,100)
random_negative = np.random.normal(-100,45,100)
N=[(x,y) for x,y in zip(random_positive,random_negative)] 
P=[(x,y) for x,y in zip(random_negative,random_positive)]

N1=[]
for i in N:
    i=i+(1,)
    N1.append(i)
P1=[]
for j in P:
    j=j+(0,)
    P1.append(j)
```

So N1 and P1 will have the output format you need.

Now when you input your "coordinate" and have to assign the "label" 1 or 0 depending on whether it belongs to N1 or P1 respectively, run the following code:

```
#lets assume that your input coordinates are "a" and "b"
(a,b)=(52.98933490111767, -59.3188037771503)
for i in N1:
    if (a,b)==(i[0],i[1]):
        z=i[2]
for j in P1:
    if (a,b)==(j[0],j[1]):
        z=j[2]
```

After running the above code, if `(a,b)` was present in `N1`, `z` will be `1` and if `(a,b)` was present in `P1`, `z` will be `0`.

Comment: This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
import numpy as np

random_positive = np.random.normal(100,45,100)
random_negative = np.random.normal(-100,45,100)
N=[(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(random_positive, random_negative, [1])] 
P=[(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(random_negative, random_positive, [0])]

print(N)
[(139.78882745432074, -58.398783286084324, 1)]
print(P)
[(-58.398783286084324, 139.78882745432074, 0)]
```

Comment: why are you using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

```
random_positive = np.random.normal(100,45,100)
random_negative = np.random.normal(-100,45,100)
N=[(x,y,1) for x,y in zip(random_positive, random_negative)] 
P=[(x,y,0) for x,y in zip(random_negative, random_positive)]
```

It is what tuples you want.

I considered your response.
What about below?

```
import numpy as np

random_positive = np.random.normal(100,45,5)
random_negative = np.random.normal(-100,45,5)
N=[(x,y) for x,y in zip(random_positive, random_negative)] 
P=[(x,y) for x,y in zip(random_negative, random_positive)]
Z1={(x,y): 1 for x, y in N}
Z2={(x,y): 0 for x, y in P}
Z=dict()
Z.update(Z1)
Z.update(Z2)
print(Z)
print(Z[N[2]])
print(Z[P[2]])
```

Comment: I don't want z to be a part of the tuple. I want sth that when I give one of the  coordinates to it later, it can return the label for that (x,y).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
random_positive = np.random.normal(100,45,100)
random_negative = np.random.normal(-100,45,100)
N=list(zip(random_positive, random_negative, [1]*len(random_positive)))
P=list(zip(random_negative, random_positive, [0]*len(random_positive)))
```

As mentioned by juanpa.arrivillaga, list() is a better way for your purpose.